# I want to design text search using search view.. that will search the whole text in android application

Tags: android, android-studio

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="60"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"/>
```

Already designed the search view bar, but unable to add functionality. please help. Design code that will search the entire text within the fragment and layout of my android application.
thanks in advance.